# React Native nested horizontal ScrollView not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to have a vertically scrollable screen with some paginated content (swipe left and right).

In the paginated content, another box with sections is placed, which has its own horizontal pagination with vertical scroll on each sub-page.

This works out of box on iOS but on android, I cannot scroll horizontally in the nested pagination scroll view. But it's child scroll view which is horizontal works fine.

I have tried all different combinations of `nestedScrollEnabled` to the prop of the `<ScrollView>`s. Including having them on none and all scrollviews.

This has been tested both on Expo and a standalone React Native app, both in appetize emulator and on a Xiaomi Pocophone F1. Same behavior, no horizontal nested scrolling.

Code here 
https://snack.expo.io/@esbenvb/scrollview-tests

Android behavior
https://vimeo.com/322265966

iOS behavior
https://vimeo.com/322266040

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.3
      CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 331.47 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28
        Build Tools: 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
        System Images: android-25 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.3 AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
      react-native: 0.58.6 => 0.58.6
```